# What is the best way to subtype numeric parameters for OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, ada, specifications

In the OpenGL specification there are certain parameters which take a set of values of the from `GL_OBJECTENUMERATIONi` with i ranging from 0 to some number indicated by something like `GL_MAX_OBJECT`. (Lights being an 'object', as one example.) It seems obvious that the number indicated is to be the upper-range is to be passed through the glGet function providing some indirection.

**However**, According to a literal interpretation of the OpenGL specification the "texture" parameter for [glActiveTexture](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glActiveTexture.xml) `must be one of GL_TEXTUREi, where i ranges from 0 (GL_MAX_COMBINED_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS - 1)` means that the set of accepted constants **must** be `GL_TEXTURE0` to `GL_TEXTURE35660` because the constant is a constant of the value 35661.

Language-lawyering aside, this setup means that the subtype can be not only disjoint, but out of order as well, such that the following C-ish mapping would be valid:

```
#define GL_TEXTURE0             0x84C0
#define GL_TEXTURE1             0x84C1
#define GL_TEXTURE2             0x84C2
#define GL_TEXTURE3             0x84A0
#define GL_TEXTURE4             0x84A4
#define GL_TEXTURE5             0x84A5
#define GL_TEXTURE6             0x84A8
#define GL_TEXTURE7             0x84A2
```

First, is this an issue actually an issue, or are the constants **always** laid out as if `GL_OBJECTi` = `GL_OBJECTi-1`+1?

If that relationship holds true then there is the possibility of using Ada's subtype feature to avoid passing in invalid parameters...

Ideally, something like:

```
-- This is an old [and incorrect] declaration using constants.
-- It's just here for an example.
SubType Texture_Number is Enum Range
  GL_TEXTURE0..Enum'Max(
            GL_MAX_TEXTURE_COORDS - 1,
            GL_MAX_COMBINED_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS - 1);
```

But, if the maximum is dynamically determined then we have to do some monkeying about:

```
With GL_Constants;
Generic
  GL_MAX_TEXTURE : Integer;
  -- ...and one of those for EACH maximum for the ranges.
Package Types is
    Use GL_Constants;

    SubType Texture_Number is Enum Range
       GL_TEXTURE0..GL_MAX_TEXTURE;    
End Types;
```

with an instantiation of `Package GL_TYPES is new Types(  GL_MAX_TEXTURE => glGet(GL_MAX_COMBINED_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS) );` and then using this new `GL_TYPES` package... a little more work, and a little more cumbersome than straight-out subtyping.

Most of this comes from being utterly new to OpenGL and not fully knowing/understanding it; but it does raise interesting questions as to the best way to proceed in building a good, thick Ada binding.

Comment: Hat tip to you for asking this question instead of just ignoring the issue like I did in my OpenGLAda binding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> means that the set of accepted constants must be GL_TEXTURE0 to GL_TEXTURE35660 because the constant is a constant of the value 35661.

No, it doesn't mean this. GL_MAX_COMBINED_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS is a implementation dependent value, that is to be queried at runtime using `glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_COMBINED_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS, out)`

Regarding the rest: The OpenGL specification states, that GL_TEXTURE = GL_TEXTURE0 + i, and similar for all other object types, with `i < n` where *n* is some reasonable number.

Answer (score 3):

This is one of those situations where I don't think getting extra-sexy with the types buys you a whole lot.

If you were to just make a special integer type for GL_TEXTURE (`type GL_TEXTURE is 16#84C0# .. 16#8B4C#;`), and use that type for all parameters looking for GL Textures, the compiler would prevent the user from doing math between those and other integer objects. That would probably be plenty. It is certianly way better than what the poor C/C++ coders are stuck with!

Then again, I've never been a proponent of super-thick Ada bindings. Ada bindings should be used to make the types more Ada-like, and to convert C error codes into exceptions. If there are other ways to save the user a bit of work, go ahead and do it. However, do not abstract away any of the power of the API!

---

There were multiple questions in the comments about my choice of using a separate numeric type rather than an Integer subtype.

It is in fact a common Ada noob mistake to start making yourself custom numeric types when `integer` subtypes will do, and then getting annoyed at all the type conversions you have to do. The classic example is someone making a type for velocity, then another type for distance, then another for force, and then finding they have to do a type conversion on every single damn math operation.

However, there are times when custom numeric types are called for. In particular, **you want to use a custom numeric type whenever objects of that type should live in a separate type universe from normal integers**. The most common occurrance of this is happens in API bindings, where the number in question is actually a C-ish designation for some resource. The is the exact situation we have here. The only math you will ever want to do on `GL_Texture`s is comparision with the type's bounds, and simple addtion and subtraction by a literal amount. (Most likely `GL_Texture'next()` will be sufficient.)

As a huge bonus, making it a custom type will prevent the common error of plugging a GL_Texture value into the wrong parameter in the API call. C API calls do love their `int`s...

In fact, if it were reasonable to sit and type them all in, I suspect you'd be tempted to just make the thing an enumeration. That'd be even less compatible with `Integer` without conversions, but nobody here would think twice about it.

Comment: The math-thing is why I want to use subtype rather than a whole new type, for parameters with a spec of "takes GL_RGB or GL_RGBA" a new type is a good choice.

Comment: Why not a subtype: `subtype gl_texture is integer range 16#84C0# .. 16#8B4C#;` This should allow you to check whether it is `in` gl_texture, but not constrain numeric operations (too badly!).

Comment: @NWS and Shark8 - I've done quite a few C-based API bindings in my time, and yes, the use of a custom numeric type is intentional. I've tried to add my logic to the answer above. In short though, don't knock it till you've tried it. :-)

Answer (score 2):

OK, first rule you need to know about OpenGL: *whenever* you see something that says, "goes from X to Y", and one of those values is a `GL_THINGY`, they are *not* talking about the numeric value of `GL_THINGY`. They are talking about an implementation-dependent value that you query *with* `GL_THINGY`. This is typically an integer, so you use some form of [`glGetIntegerv`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glGet) to query it.

Next:

> this setup means that the subtype can be not only disjoint, but out of order as well, such that the following C-ish mapping would be valid:

No, it wouldn't.

Every actual enumerator in OpenGL is assigned a specific value by the ARB. And the ARB-assigned values for the named GL_TEXTURE''i'' enumerators are:

```
#define GL_TEXTURE0 0x84C0
#define GL_TEXTURE1 0x84C1
#define GL_TEXTURE2 0x84C2
#define GL_TEXTURE3 0x84C3
#define GL_TEXTURE4 0x84C4
#define GL_TEXTURE5 0x84C5
#define GL_TEXTURE6 0x84C6
#define GL_TEXTURE7 0x84C7
#define GL_TEXTURE8 0x84C8
```

Notice how they are all in a sequential ordering.

As for the rest, let me quote you from the OpenGL 4.3 specification on [`glActiveTexture`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glActiveTexture):

> An INVALID_ENUM error is generated if an invalid texture is specified. texture is a symbolic constant of the form TEXTURE''i'', indicating that texture unit ''i'' is to be modified. The constants obey TEXTURE''i'' = TEXTURE0 + ''i'' where ''i'' is in the range 0 to ''k'' - 1, and ''k'' is the value of MAX_COMBINED_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS).

If you're creating a binding in some language, the general idea is this: ''don't strongly type certain values''. This one in particular. Just take whatever the user gives you and pass it along. If the user gets an error, they get an error.

Better yet, expose a more reasonable version of `glActiveTexture` that takes a ''integer'' instead of an enumerator and do the addition yourself.

Comment: Ah, good point [about ARB definitions]; I should have said could, not would; the first question is "are **all** iterators in OpenGL sequential?"

Comment: @Shark8: Does it matter? The only ones you should be adding values to are the index-able ones like TEXTURE0 and COLOR_ATTACHMENT0.

Comment: Very much so. That's the whole crux of the question, implementation-wise. If all of the iterator-values are sequential I can say `subtype TEXTURE is Integer range 16#84C0#..16#84C0#+NUMBER_OF_TEXTURES;` – Just because the examples I've seen have met these constraints doesn't mean that all do.

Comment: @Shark8: Except "NUMBER_OF_TEXTURES" is a *runtime*-determined value. Unless Ada allows runtime typing, that's not going to happen.

Comment: Ada does allow runtime typing. There are two ways it can be accomplished a `declare` block, or via a generic-package's parameters. The latter way has the added benefit that the parameters may be defaulted. So, in the case of textures I could default it to 80, the specification-allowed minimum.